# Storing depth data (with 16-bit depth) as auxiliary data in a JPEG file

Tags: ios, swift, jpeg, arkit, avkit

I want to be able to store the depth data of a captured ARframe in iOS in a **non-lossy** compressed image file.

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/?time=2638) WWDC talk:

"In iOS 11 we support two kinds of images with depth.
The first is HEIF HEVC, the new format, also called HEIC files, and there, there is first-class support for depth...The second format we support is JPEG. Boy, JPEG wasn't meant to do tricks like this, but we made it do this trick anyway. The map is 8-bit lossy JPEG if it's filtered, or if it has not a numbers in it, we use 16-bit lossless JPEG encoding to preserve all of the not a numbers, and we store it as a second image at the bottom of the JPEG, so it's like a multipicture object, if you're familiar with that."

When I compare the original depth buffer(16-bit) with the depth buffer I retrieve from the stored image pixel wise, I get these results:

`First        Second
0.61865234    0.6196289
0.62109375    0.6196289
0.6269531     0.6274414
0.6298828     0.63134766
0.6328125     0.63134766
nan           0.003921509
nan           0.0
nan           0.0
nan           0.007843018
nan           0.003921509`

Even when I have unfiltered depth data with NANs in it, the stored data isn't able to preserve them and neither does it use lossless encoding as it seems

This is the code I wrote:

```
if let currentFrame = session.currentFrame, let depthData = currentFrame.capturedDepthData { // The session variable is an ARSession object  
        let outputURL: URL? = filePath(forKey: "test")
        guard let cgImageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(outputURL! as CFURL, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil) else {
            return
        }

        depthData.depthDataMap.normalize() // Normalizing depth data between 0.0 and 1.0
        let sixteenBitDepthData = depthData.converting(toDepthDataType: kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat16)

        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: currentFrame.capturedImage)
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let dict: NSDictionary = [
            kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: 1.0,
            kCGImagePropertyIsFloat: kCFBooleanTrue,
        ]
        if let cgImage: CGImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) {
            CGImageDestinationAddImage(cgImageDestination, cgImage, nil)
        }

        var auxDataType: NSString?
        let auxData = sixteenBitDepthData.dictionaryRepresentation(forAuxiliaryDataType: &auxDataType)
        CGImageDestinationAddAuxiliaryDataInfo(cgImageDestination, auxDataType!, auxData! as CFDictionary)

        CGImageDestinationFinalize(cgImageDestination)

        if let second = getDepthBufferFromFile(key: "test") {
            self.compareBuffers(first: sixteenBitDepthData.depthDataMap, second: second)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've had this same issue. I've tried storing auxiliary depth in both JPEG and HEIC formats, and didn't seem to be lossless in either case. Would love a clear answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

A nature of `JPEG` file makes your trials quite senseless. iOS supports 8-bit 3-channel JPEGs or 16-bit 8-channel JPEGs. However, file formats allowing to store a true Depth information, like lossless `OpenEXR` file does, support 32-bit color data inside 1023-channels. Such a color depth is necessary for preserving a robust depth of scene. Such number of channels is necessary for storing additional useful channels.

So, in my opinion, the simplest solution in your case is to use 32-bit uncompressed or compressed `EXR` file to store Depth, Alpha, Disparity, Motion and other channels, not an Apple "hand-made" 16-bit JPEG file.